# Alternative to the Internet for a local network

Tags: network, subnet, internet, osi

Suppose we are designing a network and we want to isolate it from the Internet. Are there any alternatives to the Internet for a local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't connect the network to the Internet.

You can literally provide any service locally within your own network, without any Internet access at all. You could also connect multiple local networks with dedicated links for a larger isolated network.

In extreme, you could even use tunneled links over the Internet to provide connectivity between your endpoints, but without any connectivity between the Internet and the endpoints themselves.

Comment: Ok and how will different devices connected to our network talk to each other?

Comment: The devices could use the normal protocol stack (Ethernet, TCP/IP, applications) that you use on the Internet, or any other protocol suite that you like or develop.

Comment: So cutoff the connection of my router(s) from the Internet?

Comment: Basically, yes. Just provide all services you require locally.

Comment: You would essentially have to build a replacement for the internet otherwise you would have no purpose for the network other than local data transfer. Local networks can have a lot of functionality but to be truly functional and productive, you will likely want a connection to the internet at some point.